# getting pure xml detail from soap xml response

Tags: php, xml, web-services, soap, response

i have a .net service i am consuming from php and the result comes in the format below.

i wish to have only the contents without the soap:envelope.

How do i achieve this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope
xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body><VAccResponse xmlns="http://apps.hbng.com/"><VAccResult><VAccountSummary><Id>C0000005</Id><AccountNo>5100000014</AccountNo><AccountName>xyz HOSPITAL LTD</AccountName><SchemeCode>abc</SchemeCode><SchemeDescription>abc records</SchemeDescription><Balance>6627282</Balance><CurrencyCode>DOLLARS</CurrencyCode><AccountManagerId>F05</AccountManagerId><Debit>0</Debit><Credit>0</Credit><Tran>NO TRANSACTION DONE</Tran></VAccountSummary></VAccResult></VAccResponse></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

How do i get the xml result without the soap:body, soap envelope etc...

Comment: You can parse it using [simplexml](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php) or [DOMDocument](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadxml.php).

Comment: :@subroutines: i tried using  this  `$xmlobj = simplexml_load_string($client->response);
$xmlobj->registerXPathNamespace('soap', 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/');
foreach ($xmlobj->VKidAccount as $item) {
  echo $item->ParentCifId;
}
`  and i get this error :[ Warning: simplexml_load_string() [<a href='function.simplexml-load-string'>function.simplexml-load-string</a>]: Entity: line 1: parser error : Start tag expected, '&lt;' not found in ]

Comment: That means your xml string is invalid. Make sure you're not using `htmlentites` or `htmlspecialchars` on the string.